# what is the functionality/prupose of object casting?

Tags: java, object, casting

so i've recently come across object casting in java, and i understand what casting is, i just don't understand how casting with objects works, or what the functionality is/how casting modifies the object. i am very confused and i have no idea of even how this could ever be used.

take `a name = new b()`, why would you cast b into a or whatever its doing? i'm pretty confused. i don't really understand how b changes when its casted to a. is there actually any reason to ever use this?

tl;dr i don't understand *how* it works or *why* you'd ever use it.

Comment: You should read about polymorphism - that will help you understand the purpose of that.

Comment: FYI, what you're showing is not casting. `b another = (a)name` would be a cast.

Comment: "i understand what casting is" + "i don't really understand how b changes" => then you do **not** understand what casting is, because it does not change any object, ever, at all.

Comment: @Amongalen ive already read about polymorphism

Comment: @anashyean, you are asking wrong question over here. You first need to understand OOPS concepts. Then you can understand this.

Comment: @Jayesh Choudhary i understand casting between primitive types... but not between objects, and im doing a tutorial that i found had built up on itself without leaving any gaps up until object casting

Comment: @anashyean, are you familiar with Inheritance ? A child class object can be type cast in parent class. Since Object is Super class or all classes therefore any object can be cast into object Class. e.g. Object o = new Test();

Answer (score 1):

Cast is a hint for a compiler (needed of compiler cannot prove the typing contracts are correct) that you as a programmer guarantee that object is of a type you are casting it into.

There is no conversion happening to the object.

Comment: but if ```b another = (a)name``` is done, then does ```another``` get the methods of class b or class a?

Comment: @anashyean it will get the methods of `b` (if that piece of code compiles to begin with). But remember that if `name` didn't have those methods to begin with, you'll have a runtime exception when calling them.

Answer (score 0):

> how casting modifies the object

Casting does not modify the object. Casting a reference type is a way to tell the compiler: "look, I have this variable of type A here, but I want you to treat it as if it is of type B".

This is sometimes needed because you know better than the compiler what the actual type of the object is you're working with. Note that a check will still be done at runtime - if at that time the object is not of the correct type, you will get a `ClassCastException`.

> take `a name = new b()`

That is not casting. There you just assign an object of type `b` to a variable of type `a`, which is only allowed if type `a` is a supertype of `b`.

Casting is when you use the type between round braces, for example:

```
Object something = new House();

// At this point, the compiler doesn't know that 'something' refers to a House.
// You can cast it:
House house = (House) something;
```

Casting was often necessary in the time before Java had generics (Java 1.4 and older), because collections such as `ArrayList` did not know what types of objects they were holding.

You should avoid casting as much as possible - it's really a way to circumvent the compiler's type checking, and makes your code less type-safe. Only use casting when absolutely necessary.

Comment: so in your example, ```something``` is first of type object, but then you cast it into type house?

Comment: @anashyean Yes. You have to understand that a **variable** and an **object** are not the same thing. A variable is a **reference** to an object. The variable `something` has the type `Object`, so it can refer to any type of object. In this case it refers to an object of type `House`. If you need to do anything with it that is specific to `House` objects, you need to cast it.